# How to Draw Highlight Behind Richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

Using this code, it draws the highlight on the text, which makes the text somehow blur?

```
Public Class HighlightableRTB
Inherits RichTextBox

Private LineHeight As Integer = 15

Public Sub New()
    HighlightColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

<Category("Custom"), Description("Specifies the highlight color.")>
Public Property HighlightColor As Color

Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectionChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnSelectionChanged(e)
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Const WM_PAINT As Integer = 15

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_PAINT Then
        Dim selectLength = Me.SelectionLength
        Dim selectStart = Me.SelectionStart
        Me.Invalidate()
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        If selectLength > 0 Then Return

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Me.Handle)
            Dim b As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, HighlightColor))
            Dim line = Me.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectStart)
            Dim loc = Me.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Me.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line))
            g.FillRectangle(b, New Rectangle(loc, New Size(Me.Width, LineHeight)))
        End Using
    Else
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

How can one draw the rectangle highlight behind the text of the richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

As you already guessed, the text is not really "blurry"... it's the yellow rectangle which is painted over it that makes it looks that way.

This is not going to be easy. In fact, I have a solution, but it's not something I would recommend... if I had anything else to say. But I haven't, so here's one way to deal with this issue:

You can paint the text... over the text. It doesn't remove the text which already exists... but paints over it. If your coordinates are a little bit off, it'll look like crap, but if you get the exact right place it'll work like a charm. An awful, hacky charm:

```
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Me.Handle)
    Dim b As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, HighlightColor))
    Dim line = Me.GetLineFromCharIndex(Me.SelectionStart)
    Dim loc = Me.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Me.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line))
    g.FillRectangle(b, New Rectangle(loc, New Size(Me.Width, LineHeight)))
    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Me.Text, Font, New Point(-2, 1), ForeColor) ' this is the important line!
End Using
```

[image: Hacky charm!]

This is 100% a hack, though, and I sure hope that somebody with more sense than I chime in. The position I wrote (-2, 1) should do the trick, but if somehow it doesn't, you can get rid of the transparency to hide your shame by replacing `Color.FromArgb(50, HighlightColor)` by `Color.FromArgb(255, HighlightColor)`. It won't be *that* obvious since the text will only reveal this dirty trick when someone selects it (try it!).

Have fun!

Comment: The highlight did not follow the current line of caret. It's painting everything. Also, the text drawn is not putting in the actual text that suppose to be on the highlight when scrolled down. What I actually want is that type that's in Notepad++, you know it paints the background of the current line that the caret is while the text still remain sharp. So if there is any other means to achieve this, I'll appreciate.

Comment: That's because I modified this part: `New Size(Me.Width, Me.Lines.Count * LineHeight)` so every line would be yellow. Your original code was only painting the first line. I'm updating the code snippet with some new values and an image.

Comment: Did this fix your issue? If you fixed another way, you can also post your own answer, as it may be useful to a future user having a similar problem.